# How to hide-show multiple divs using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Alright, so I want to show two divs when selecting on of the options in my selector.

This is what I have currently, works great and hiding and showing elements based on option selected. But doesnt work If i want 2 divs to show on based on sections. Help would be much appreciated.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#colorselector').change(function() {
    $('.colors').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<Select id="colorselector">
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</Select>
<div id="red" class="colors" style="display:none"> red... </div>
<div id="yellow" class="colors" style="display:none"> yellow.. </div>
<div id="blue" class="colors" style="display:none"> blue.. </div>
```

Comment: Does that mean you have 2 divs with id 'red' for example?

Comment: If you don’t tell us which elements you wish to show, and how your jQuery is supposed to recognise which elements they would be, we’re limited in the help we can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what 2 div's you want to show, but hes an example. I've switch out id for a command class by color:

```
$(function() {
  $('#colorselector').change(function() {
    $('.colors').hide();
    $('.colors.' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  $('#colorselector').change(function() {
    $('.colors').hide();
    $('.colors.' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<Select id="colorselector">
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</Select>
<div class="colors red" style="display:none"> red... </div>
<div class="colors yellow" style="display:none"> yellow.. </div>
<div class="colors blue" style="display:none"> blue..1 </div>

<div class="colors blue" style="display:none"> blue..2 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide/show more than one element then you should work with class names instead of IDs:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#colorselector').change(function() {
    $('.colors').hide()
    if (this.value>"") $('.colors.'+this.value).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.colors {font-weight:900; padding:10px; color: white}
.red {background-color:red}
.yellow {background-color:yellow; color:black;}
.blue {background-color:blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<Select id="colorselector">
  <option value="">select a color ...</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</Select>
<div class="red colors" style="display:none"> red... </div>
<div class="yellow colors" style="display:none"> yellow.. </div>
<div class="blue colors" style="display:none"> blue.. </div>
<h2>Another section with further divs</h2>
<div class="red colors" style="display:none">more red... </div>
<div class="yellow colors" style="display:none">and yellow.. </div>
<div class="blue colors" style="display:none">or even blue.. </div>
```